# The remote server returned an error (400) Bad Request, status ProtocolError

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebresponse, bad-request, http-response-codes

I couldn't find the solution in the other similar questions. 
I am getting The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request error while running the following code.

```
string url = @"http://api.dwaybill.com/" + cid + 
               "/orders.json?v=" + version + "&key=" + key + 
               "&customer_number=" + customer_number + 
               "&password=" + password;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

byte[] bytes1 = encoding.GetBytes(@"{"Here is the json text that i testet and is correct"}");

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = bytes1.Length;

using (Stream sendStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    sendStream.Write(bytes1, 0, bytes1.Length);
}
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(html);
```

While getting the response via `(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())`, I am getting **400 Bad Request** error.

How can I solve this problem? What should I do?

edit: this is the API that Im trying to make a post request: https://github.com/digwaybill/Digital-Waybill-API

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `rest` api but do you not need to close/flush the request. Can you single step through your code and spot when the error occurs?

Comment: if you use "using()" you don't need to close/flush @PeterSmith

Comment: @PeterSmith the code occurs here (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())  and status is protocol error

Comment: Check whether the content of `url` is correct. `Bad request` means occurs if the "*Gateway [is] unable to handle the request URI provided*, or the HTTP request itself was invalid." so maybe the `url` is just incorrect/invalid/ contains spaces or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the error is because of missing headers.

Please add the below headers before the request in the format:

```
request.Headers["X-My-Custom-Header"] = "the-value";
```

For your example, it would be:

```
request.Headers["Accept"] = " application/json";
```

Please update the line for JSON as below. Json needs a key and value. Feel free to update the `name` to any other string. Also the double quotes is interfering with the string format, which has to be escaped.

```
byte[] bytes1 = encoding.GetBytes("{\"name\":\"Here is the json text that i testet and is correct\"}");
```

Comment: I added it, still i am getting 400 bad request

Comment: I tried it it looks like something is wrong with my json data : "status": 400,
    "error": "A JSON parsing error occurred: Missing '}': ntact\": {\r\n         \r\nMissing '}': ntact\": {\r\n         \r\nMissing ']': ntact\": {\r\n         \r\nMissing '}': ntact\": {\r\n         \r\n",
    "body": "
} @Habeeb

Comment: this is the string {"customer_number":"DYN833",
"cost_center": "AJ Omnicare",
"order_type": "Delivery",
"ready_time": "Tue, 08 Jan 2013 08:58:59",
"round_trip": false,
"route_stops": [{"company": "my company pickup",
"address": "1639 11th Street",
"suite": "210",
"city": "Santa Monica",
"state": "CA",
"postal_code": "90049",
"country": "United States",
"contact": {
"name": "Bradley Snyder",
"phone": "8005753510"}]} it continues. @Habeeb

Comment: @bs are you use the Json string is well formatted and broken structure?

Comment: Json data were wrong, I had to remove something form the documentation to make it work.@Habeeb